# SXA Search results Tooltip

Tags: sxa, content-search

The SXA search results tool-tip contains the display name of the item as shown in image below 
[image]

I want to make the tool-tip reads its content from a specific field of the item template, as I have a rendering variant that contains many fields of different templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search Results rendering is using Rendering Variants to display results. If you want to modify how HTML of particular search results item is generated then you would need to override Rendering Variants logic (that might be pretty hard). We are using Field Renderers (Sitecore is generating HTML) there like that:

```
FieldRenderer fieldRender = new FieldRenderer
{
    Item = item,
    FieldName = variantField.FieldName,
    ...
};
```

This HTML is later on put on the fronted into `<ul><li>` list. And as far as I can see in the code we are not adding any tooltips there. So the tooltip comes from Field Renderer probably.

Beside all above you can try use Rendering Variant tokens:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, the second method worked, but I wrote title instead of tooltip, when I wrote tooltip it didn't work, Can you please tell me the difference

Comment: The syntax is $(FIELD_NAME). When you will replace FIELD_NAME with "Title" then text from Title field will be taken. When you will put there different field name than different value will be taken (of course that field must exist on the item).